# Changing value datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is it possible to change the value of the selected data?

So, when they choose the month October it will submit value="10" but it has to change to value="9".

Is this possible?

I'm using following code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
$(window).load(function(){
$(".date_year").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    //buttonImage: "calendar_icon.png", 
    buttonText: 'Cal',
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    showAnim: 'fadeIn',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',



    onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
        dateArr = dateText.split('/');
        $(this).siblings('.date_month').val(dateArr[1]);
        $(this).siblings('.date_day').val(dateArr[0]);
        $(this).val(dateArr[2]);
    }
});
});>  
</script>
```

And my html is:

```
    <div class="date-picker">
    <label for="preferredDate">Arrival</label>
    <input type="text" class="date_day" name="day_a" />/
    <input type="text" class="date_month" name="month_a" />/
    <input type="text" class="date_year" name="year_a" />
</div>
<div class="date-picker">
    <label for="preferredDate">Departure</label>
    <input type="text" class="date_day" name="day_d" />/
    <input type="text" class="date_month" name="month_d" />/
    <input type="text" class="date_year" name="year_d"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using a function that modifies the date when a user is done picking, I'm not sure if you wrote that yourself or got it from somewhere but let me explain:

```
// when the user is done picking the date, this function runs
onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
    //the date is split into day, month year (by taking the pieces between /'s)
    dateArr = dateText.split('/');

    // the second part of the split date string is the month, put it in the .date_month box
    $(this).siblings('.date_month').val(dateArr[1]);

    // same with the day and year respectively
    $(this).siblings('.date_day').val(dateArr[0]);
    $(this).val(dateArr[2]);
}
```

At the point where you put the date in the box, you could add some extra script. Replace the line that sets the `.date_month` value with:

```
var month = dateArr[1];
var newMonth = month - 1; //or whatever changes you want to make to the month
$(this).siblings('.date_month').val(newMonth);
```

Of course you can just do it the short way:

```
    $(this).siblings('.date_month').val(newMonth - 1);
```

I split it up to show a bit more clearly what happens, and should also see that at the `newMonth` part you'll be able to do some more calculations if you want before actually putting it into the month field.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your reply, this do work but the problem is that the changed value is now visible in the input-field. The user may not see the changed value, it's only important to send the correct value to the other server.  Would this be possible?

Comment: Then it's not something that the datepicker can do. All the datepicker does is fill in a field, submitting the fields to the server is not part of the script. You will have to make a script that changes the value of the submitted fields right before it is sent.